# Approach to interpret the following confusion matrix

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I know that from the confusion matrix, we can figure out how good a classifier is in terms of guessing what is right and wrong.

In the case below, I have sample of the following data:

[image]

After running the Random Tree classifier, I get the following results.

[image]

Does that mean that out of the `build wind float`, the classifier was only able to get 53/70 correct?

Or in the case of the `build wind non float`, the classifier was only able to get 53/76 correct?

Just need some clarity - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. While the columns represent "classified as", the rows indicate the true label.

So for `build wind float` the confusion matrix can be read as:

From all the samples we have labeled with class a:

- 53 were classified as a (true positives here)
- 11 were classified a b
- 6 were classified as c
- ...

So you find the correct guesses at the diagonal of the matrix and the for the rest you can see which classes were assigned instead.